# Lidgren.Network high latency

Tags: c#, networking, local, monogame, lidgren

I am using Lidgren.Network to connect to a local server and pulling messages in a 60hz frequenz both on server and client.

The problem is that the average roundtrip time is something around 2ms, which is okay, but when sending a small message it require between 1 seconds and 3 seconds for the way from the client to the server to another client.

The content of the message are just 3 variableUint32 data.

If I'm not wrong in the worst case scenario the maximal time for the packet should be 32ms (16ms for being processed by the server and 16ms again for being processed on the other client).